# Programmatically access SharePoint Online ZIP service

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, gzip

In SharePoint Online we have a feature where we can select multiple files in document library and it downloads them in a ZIP file. I inspected this feature and it makes a call to a ZIP service at the URL `https://....svc.ms/transform/zip`.

It passes the file details to this service in below format:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "<FILE1>",
            "size": 1234,
            "docId": "https://<SITE>.sharepoint.com:443/_api/v2.0/drives/b!...",
            "isFolder": false
        },
        {
            "name": "<FILE2>",
            "size": 4321,
            "docId": "https://<SITE>.sharepoint.com:443/_api/v2.0/drives/b!...",
            "isFolder": false
        }
    ]
}
```

The `docId` doesn't look anything like the file URL in SharePoint Online.

Is there a way I can use this service to pass our own files (which are present in the document library) and get ZIP file? Or should I be looking for custom solutions?

Comment: Wondering if you ever found a solution for this. I have a custom spfx webpart that allows users to download numerous files in a zipped format, but when there are 200+ files the error handling becomes a bit unruly and it would be handy just to be able to use this built in service that the document libraries have. Thanks in advance. -JD

Comment: @user110928: No I did not :(